# Estou recebendo esse erro ao tentar conectar o mysql: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

conexao.php

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$banco;charset=utf8", $usuario, $senha);
    return $conn;
}catch(PDOException $e){
    throw new PDOException($e);
}
```

base.php

```
        require 'conexao.php';
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION['login']) and !empty($_SESSION['login'])){
          $sql = $conn->prepare("select * from usuarios where id=:user;");
          $sql->execute(':user', $_SESSION['login']);
          $user = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

login.php

```
<?php
include 'conexao.php';
//inicia a sessão
session_start();

//recebe o nome do usuário
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
//recebe a senha do usuário
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

//verifica se existe um usuário com esse nome e senha
$stmt = $conn->prepare('select * from usuarios where nome=:nome and senha=:pass;');
$stmt->bindParam(':nome',$nome);
$stmt->bindParam(':pass',$senha);
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

//se o resultado retornou o id do usuário
if($user->id > 0){
    //cria-se a sessão 'login' que recebe esse id
    $_SESSION['login'] = $user->id;
    //carrega página index
    header('location: ./index.php');
}
```

Tambem está dando erro aqui na linha 18 onde $sql recebe $conn

index.php

```
<?php require 'conexao.php'; ?>
<?php require 'base.php'; ?>
<?php

//se o usuário escreveu algo no campo de busca
if(isset($_POST['pesquisa']) and !empty($_POST['pesquisa'])){
    //recebe o texto do post de busca
    $pesquisa = $_POST['pesquisa'];

    //verifica se existem formulário com o valor de $pesquisa no nome
    $sql = $conn->prepare("select * from formulario where nome like '%$pesquisa%';");
    $sql->execute();
    $rows = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

//senão
}else{
    //busca todos os formulários organizando-os de acordo com a data da ultima alteração em ordem decrescente
    $sql = $conn->prepare("select * from formulario order by data_modificacao desc;");
    $sql->execute();
    $rows = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Comment: O erro claramente diz que está chamando o método `prepare` em um objeto nulo, `$conn`. Veja porque `$conn` é nulo; seja porque a conexão falou ou porque não atribuiu valor à variável. Verifique também o arquivo de log de erros do seu servidor para ver as possíveis mensagens de erro que ocorreram no processo.

Comment: agora está mostrando esse erro: Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\Users\User\Documents\Trabalhos\FormGenerator\asdfg\index.php on line 18.     Parece que o require 'conexao.php' não está funcionando..

Comment: Bom, isso mostra que a sua variável realmente não está definida...

Comment: mas como, se ela está em try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$banco;charset=utf8",$usuario, $senha);

Comment: Mas aparentemente elas não estão no mesmo arquivo, estão? Faça um [mcve] que reproduza o problema para analisarmos melhor.

Comment: Onde eu posso mandar esse  exemplo? Faço ele como outra pergunta ou mando por aqui mesmo? Desculpa o incomodo mas é o meu primeiro projeto em php..

Comment: Pode [edit] a pergunta

Comment: Colocando `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` depois que atribui a `$conn` (no arquivo `conexao.php`), acontece alguma coisa diferente?

Comment: não, o erro continua o mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa maneira

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("select * from usuarios where id = :user");
$sql->execute([':user' => $_SESSION['login']); 
$user = $sql->fetcObject();
```

Sobre a porta que você não consegue utilizar, ela deve estar sendo utilizada por outro programa, por isso não consegue abrir o servidor PHP nela,

Prefira também utilizar um objeto ao invés de utilizar o bindParam, faça um objeto com tudo que precisa, por exemplo

```
$obj = [
   ':login' => $login,
   ':senha' => $senha,
   ':email' => $email
];
```

E depois passar dentro do execute

```
$sql->execute($obj);
```

Comment: Por que mudar a SQL irá afetar o valor do objeto `$conn`, que é nulo de acordo com a mensagem de erro?